# rewrite rule for subfolder index

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, security, mod-rewrite

i have this url

```
http://myurl.com/shiftturn/index.php?m=value
```

and i want:

```
http://myurl.com/shiftturn/value
```

this is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /shiftturn/([^/]*)$ /index.php?m=$1 [L]
```

but doesn't work.
how can I do to get the kind of url I need, with a correct htaccess expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this rule in `/shiftturn/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /shiftturn/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?m=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?m=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: What original URL do you see?

Comment: Thanks @zx81, your regex answers already tell me that you can handle these rewrite-fu pretty well too

Comment: Thank you anubhava... But there is **much more** to your rewrite answers than the regex! You are fluent in details of the Apache syntax. Also I don't have a good way to test rewrites. I don't feel like uploading files to a web server for instance. I have seen a couple online rewrite testers, but haven't really taken the plunge. These are two reasons why I don't feel able to answer rewrite questions at the moment.

Comment: Actually all these online testers are pretty useless. I just needed a plain vanilla Apache server running on my laptop to test these rules.